# How to fix invalid conversion error when including linux cn_proc.h header in C++ code

Tags: c++, linux, enums, linux-kernel-headers

Since [23 July 2023](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/743acf351bae1ff7ff4aaadd6a406d4d6091d90b) the `cn_proc.h` linux header contains the following:

```cpp
#define PROC_EVENT_ALL (PROC_EVENT_FORK | PROC_EVENT_EXEC | PROC_EVENT_UID |  \
            PROC_EVENT_GID | PROC_EVENT_SID | PROC_EVENT_PTRACE | \
            PROC_EVENT_COMM | PROC_EVENT_NONZERO_EXIT |           \
            PROC_EVENT_COREDUMP | PROC_EVENT_EXIT)

/*
 * If you add an entry in proc_cn_event, make sure you add it in
 * PROC_EVENT_ALL above as well.
 */
enum proc_cn_event {
    /* Use successive bits so the enums can be used to record
     * sets of events as well
     */
    PROC_EVENT_NONE = 0x00000000,
    PROC_EVENT_FORK = 0x00000001,
    PROC_EVENT_EXEC = 0x00000002,
    PROC_EVENT_UID  = 0x00000004,
    PROC_EVENT_GID  = 0x00000040,
    PROC_EVENT_SID  = 0x00000080,
    PROC_EVENT_PTRACE = 0x00000100,
    PROC_EVENT_COMM = 0x00000200,
    /* "next" should be 0x00000400 */
    /* "last" is the last process event: exit,
     * while "next to last" is coredumping event
     * before that is report only if process dies
     * with non-zero exit status
     */
    PROC_EVENT_NONZERO_EXIT = 0x20000000,
    PROC_EVENT_COREDUMP = 0x40000000,
    PROC_EVENT_EXIT = 0x80000000
};

/* [some unrelated code removed] */

static inline enum proc_cn_event valid_event(enum proc_cn_event ev_type)
{
    ev_type &= PROC_EVENT_ALL;
    return ev_type;
}
```

This means that if you’re compiling the following minimal breaking example on kernel 6.5.6:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#include <linux/cn_proc.h>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Compilation fails with the following error:

```
/usr/include/linux/cn_proc.h: In function ‘proc_cn_event valid_event(proc_cn_event)’:
/usr/include/linux/cn_proc.h:72:17: error: invalid conversion from ‘unsigned int’ to ‘proc_cn_event’ [-fpermissive]
   72 |         ev_type &= PROC_EVENT_ALL;
      |                 ^
      |                 |
      |                 unsigned int
```

It seems the `|`-aggregate of `enum proc_cn_event` values that is `PROC_EVENT_ALL` is considered, in C++, as an `unsigned int` and not an `enum proc_cn_event`, nor an `int` which seems to be the underlying type for `enum proc_cn_event`.

(Tested on g++ 13.1 and clang++ 17.0)

Note that:

- The header compiles fine as C code
- Wrapping the include statement in `extern "C" { … }` does not fix this issue
- Prepending a forward declaration `enum proc_cn_event : unsigned int;` to the include to force the underlying type to be `unsigned int` fails with:

  ```
  /usr/include/linux/cn_proc.h:42:6: error: enumeration previously declared with fixed underlying type
      42 | enum proc_cn_event {
         |      ^
  test.cpp:3:6: note: previous declaration is here
       3 | enum proc_cn_event : unsigned int;
         |      ^
  ```

I’m not sure whether I am doing this wrong and there is a proper way to include that header in C++ code, or whether I should not be trying to include it in C++ code at all (seems a bit drastic).

So how can I make this compile, without using `-fpermissive`? Can I maybe add something to my C++ code to make this compile (maybe something implicitly converting `unsigned int` to `enum proc_cn_event` values?)

Comment: I think you'll need to disable the diagnostic for the include - perhaps using a `#pragma gcc diag push`/`pop` pair around it.

Comment: I guess the reason that `PROC_EVENT_ALL` is unsigned is that `PROC_EVENT_EXIT = 0x80000000` exceeds the range of `signed int` on this platform.

Comment: Can you write wrappers in C for the part that needs this header, and then use those C functions from your C++ code?

Comment: Well it's a C header. Compiling it with a C++ compiler is at your own risk. The proper way to fix the problem is to submit a PR to make the code C++-compatible.